# Поиск подстроки и скобочных групп

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, подстрока

Я пытаюсь найти целую строку и все скобочные группы. Я хочу сделать это в строке:

> contract var str = "contract CryptoGO is StandardToken, Babaika, Pisos, Banana { string public name; uint8 public decimals; string public symbol; string public version = 'H1.0'; uint256 public unitsOneEthCanBuy; uint256 public totalEthInWei; address public fundsWallet; function CryptoGOToken() { balances[msg.sender] = 1000000000000000000000000000; totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000000; name = \"CryptoGO\"; decimals = 18; symbol = \"CGO\"; unitsOneEthCanBuy = 10000; fundsWallet = msg.sender; } function() payable{ totalEthInWei = totalEthInWei + msg.value; uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy; if (balances[fundsWallet] < amount) { return; } balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet] - amount; balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + amount; Transfer(fundsWallet, msg.sender, amount); fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value); } function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) { allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value; Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value); if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3(\"receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)\"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { throw; } return true; }}";

Пример моего кода:

```js
var str = "contract CryptoGO is StandardToken, Babaika, Pisos, Banana {   string public name;    uint8 public decimals;    string public symbol;    string public version = 'H1.0';    uint256 public unitsOneEthCanBuy;    uint256 public totalEthInWei;    address public fundsWallet;    function CryptoGOToken() {        balances[msg.sender] = 1000000000000000000000000000;        totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000000;       name = \"CryptoGO\";        decimals = 18;        symbol = \"CGO\";        unitsOneEthCanBuy = 10000;        fundsWallet = msg.sender;    }    function() payable{        totalEthInWei = totalEthInWei + msg.value;        uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy;        if (balances[fundsWallet] < amount) {            return;        }        balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet] - amount;        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + amount;        Transfer(fundsWallet, msg.sender, amount);        fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);   }    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) {        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);        if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3(\"receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)\"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { throw; }        return true;    }}";
            var re = /[^(//)]?\s?contract\s+([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\s*is?\s+([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\s*[, {]/ig;
            var res
            while ((res = re.exec(str)) != null) {
                   console.log(res);
            }
```

Сейчас я имею вывод:

```
[
  "contract CryptoGO is StandardToken,",
  "CryptoGO",
  "StandardToken"
]
```

А хочу получить следующий вывод:

```
[contract CryptoGO is StandardToken, Babaika, Banana {,
CryptoGO,
StandardToken,
Babaika,
Banana]
```

Как правильно переписать регулярное выражение, чтобы оно давало ожидаемый вывод?

Comment: то есть, Вы хотите регуляркой распарсить javascript код?

Comment: solidity код, ищу по файлу. Там в файле еще есть контракты такого рода.